# Creating local database with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have problem with creating local db with EF code first. When I try create db with command `update-database` Visual Studio returns the error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

In earlier project I haven't any problem with do that.

Context Class

```
public class Context : DbContext {

    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        modelBuilder.Ignore<IIdentifableEntity>();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasKey(p => p.Id).Ignore(p => p.EntityId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasKey(t => t.Id).Ignore(t => t.EntityId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasKey(t => t.Id).Ignore(t => t.EntityId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.Id).Ignore(u => u.EntityId);
    }

}
```

[App.config](https://gist.github.com/KSYMEK/2f1b3d4a1a3b8551a58e964008fa38cd#file-gistfile1-txt)

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Maybe showing a connection string could be relevant?

Comment: I'm using default connection string in app.config

Comment: Please show it, thanks!

Comment: @do you have an instance named `mssqllocaldb`? Can you connect to it using SSMS?

Comment: All works after reinstall SQL server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection string is valid and working with the reference database associated with respective username and password.
You can check your database is connecting using SQL server management studio.